# The HTML file changed on server is not reflected

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Deployed django project using DigitalOcean.
After confirming with the server IP address, the site was displayed.
However, there is a part that I want to modify, and the template folder of django is HTML
I edited some.
And even after checking nginx after reloading, it was not reflected.
However, the cause is unknown because of the first deployment.

I would like to ask about this cause.
Does that mean that the displayed HTML is not a template folder display?
I would like to know how to fix it.

**Postscript**
please tell me.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon (apasn)
Requires=apasn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=administrator
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/administrator/apasn
ExecStart=/home/administrator/apasn/venv/bin/gunicorn \
--access-logfile - \
--workers 3 \
--bind unix:/run/gunicorn/apasn.sock \
person_manager.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: what wsgi server are you using? gunicorn? uwsgi? You need to restart that when you update any of your code.

Comment: I am using gunicorn.

Comment: `service gunicorn-<name>.service restart`, depends how you named your systemd file. check in **/etc/systemd/system**

Comment: I was able to do it.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django uses a cache with the templates so restarting nginx won't do anything right away. There are a few things that you can do:

First, try restarting gunicorn:

`sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`

See if that fixes it. If not, switch debug mode on with `DEBUG = True` in `settings.py` and then restart gunicorn. You will definitely see the changes at that point. Then, turn debug mode back off with `DEBUG = False` and then restart gunicorn again.

Comment: “Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.”An error was output.

Comment: It was done after confirming the pass and going carefully.
I didn't think it was gunicorn.
Thank you very much.

Comment: That's because you weren't using `gunicorn` as a `systemctl` service :) Glad it's fixed though!